# Material-UI Menu issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, menu-items

I want the menu to give height 100%. If the elements in the page increases vertically then with respect to the page length the menu-height will also be increasing. I have used "**height:100%**" in the **styles** but it's not working.

**Any help??**

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import './mystyle.css';

const mainmenu = {
 width: '180px',
 height: '100%',
};

class MenuView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="dash-menuview">
           <Menu style={mainmenu} className="mydashboard">
             <MenuItem primaryText="My Name" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/name" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
             <MenuItem primaryText="Personal Information" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/information" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
             <MenuItem primaryText="My Address" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/current" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
             <MenuItem primaryText="My Files" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/files" onClick={handlers.logout}/>  
           </Menu>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MenuView;
```

**mystyle.css**

```
.dash-menuview {
   margin-left: -8.8%;
}
.mydashboard a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Will you please set a plunkr for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `height: 100vh` like below code, where I just put a sample output of you code.

```css
.dash-menuview {
   margin-left: 0;
   background :#444;
   height: 100vh;
}
.mydashboard a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dash-menuview">
    <Menu class="mydashboard">
        <a href="#">My Name</a>
        <a href="#">Personal Information</a>
        <a href="#">My Address</a>
        <a href="#">My Files</a>  
    </Menu>
</div>
```

You can also check this [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/36j7demj/) Hope it's helpful.